# How to add floating button clickable response in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to add floating button with drawerlayout but when i added floating button on required posiotion the option menu doesn't work after adding floating button can anyone help me to adding floating button and work all menu item properly.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bskes.zonevi.ui.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/verticalLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/navactionbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navheader"
        app:menu="@menu/navlist">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

example like this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brUA3.png)

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Keshab 
According to given image link, follow some github link. may be help you.

https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton

https://github.com/nitemarket/floating-button-menu

https://github.com/noln/android-floating-action-button

https://github.com/rofiqsetiawan/OneMoreFabMenuDemo

Comment: Thanks for sharing github link sir